# when ckfinder popup, cannot show the images

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckfinder

ckeditor integrate with ckfinder.
when I click browser from ckeditor, ckfinder appears but cannot show images and folders. the error will be like that.

```
It was not possible to properly load the XML response from the web server.
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location: http://localhost/tess/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Images&CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en Line Number 2, Column 1:Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tess/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php5/Utils/Misc.php on line 202
^
Raw response from the server:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><br />
<b>Notice</b>: A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tess/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php5/Utils/Misc.php</b> on line <b>202</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tess/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php5/Utils/Misc.php</b> on line <b>202</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tess/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php5/Utils/Misc.php</b> on line <b>202</b><br />
<Connector resourceType="Images"><Error number="0" /><ConnectorInfo enabled="true" s="" c="" thumbsEnabled="true" thumbsUrl="http://localhost/ckeditor-ckfinder-integration/uploads/_thumbs/" thumbsDirectAccess="false" thumbsWidth="100" thumbsHeight="100" imgWidth="1600" imgHeight="1200" uploadMaxSize="134217728" uploadCheckImages="false" plugins="imageresize,fileeditor,zip" /><ResourceTypes><ResourceType name="Images" url="http://localhost/ckeditor-ckfinder-integration/uploads/images/" allowedExtensions="bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png" deniedExtensions="" hash="3425a9286fe54f22" hasChildren="false" acl="255" maxSize="134217728" /></ResourceTypes><PluginsInfo><imageresize smallThumb="90x90" mediumThumb="120x120" largeThumb="180x180" /></PluginsInfo></Connector>
```

the error shows like followings:

[image]

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: I think so yes.

Comment: Would you share it, please?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by just comments ckfinder\core\connector\php\php5\Utils\Misc.php line no 196 to 205 then it works fine. You comment below code.

```
        $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a single line before the switch case as below in the ckfinder\core\connector\php\php5\Utils\Misc.php between line no 196 to 205:

```
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);

    $val=substr($val, 0, -1); // This is the new added line.


switch($last) {
    // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
    case 'g':
        $val *= 1024;
    case 'm':
        $val *= 1024;
    case 'k':
        $val *= 1024;
}
```

---

It will solve your current problem. If you get any further problems, please comment to me.